# RecordType using Test.loadData in Testclass for account object

Tags: apex, failing-tests, test-setup, test.loaddata

I am trying to export data in csv from one sandbox and trying to load the same data into Test class using `loadData` method. Currently , I am struggling in creating `RecordType` within Test class

For example, I do have account data in csv format mentioned below

```
"Id","PersonEmail","LastName","RecordTypeId"
"0011C00002YT983QAD","vc404@gmail.com","Chahal","01215000001RATXAA4"
```

Now when I run above data using below code it throws `Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)`

```
    List<sObject> accountList = Test.loadData(Account.getSObjectType(), 'AccountSample');
```

I have covered all the required fields in CSV data but it looks like `RecordTypeId` is creating an issue as Test Class does not know about the `RecordType` data.

So I don't know how would I load `RecordType` data in Test Class using `loadData` itself. I am aware that using following code I can get the Id of `RecordType` but how would I add those into my CSV file.

```
    Id RecordTypeIdAccount = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
```

Comment: Loaddata inserts the data and you don't need an ID in the insert call. So you can remove the ID column. Also, can you put the complete error message, there should be something after that Errors while saving records.

Comment: Well i just realized that the data that I am importing has to be `Person Account` but not sure how to load that in test class